# React Native Error: No bridge implementation is available, giving up

Tags: ios, react-native, objective-c-runtime

I just created a new React Native project. The project is actually an integration of React Native into a native iOS project. When I run the app I get an exception in `RCTBridge.m` in a function called `bridgeClass`:

```
RCTAssert(implClass != nil, @"No bridge implementation is available, giving up.");
```

I am creating a bridge manager in my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
self.bridgeManager = [[ReactBridgeManager alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

My implementation of ReactBridgeManager looks like this:

```
@interface ReactBridgeManager () <RCTBridgeDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) RCTBridge *bridge;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *bundleURL;

@end

@implementation ReactBridgeManager

- (instancetype)initWithBundleURL:(NSURL *)bundleURL launchOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.bundleURL = bundleURL;
        self.bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - RCTBridgeDelegate

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
    return self.bundleURL;
}

@end
```

Here are the version numbers of React and React Native from my `package.json`:

```
"react": "^15.6.1",
"react-native": "^0.47.2",
```

Does anyone know why this exception is being thrown and what I might have to do to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

In `RCTBridge.m` in function `bridgeClass` (line 276-277):

```
Class batchedBridgeClass = objc_lookUpClass("RCTBatchedBridge");
Class cxxBridgeClass = objc_lookUpClass("RCTCxxBridge");
```

The `batchedBridgeClass` and the `cxxBridgeClass` are `0x0` after `objc_lookUpClass()` is called. It seems `implClass` will always be `nil` because `batchedBridgeClass` and `cxxBridgeClass` are always `nil`.

`objc_lookUpClass()` will return `nil` if the class is not registered with the Objective-C runtime. **I will need to look into what might cause those classes not to be registered.** Please help if you can!

[Filed Github Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15655)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this,selected your `project target` -> `Build Settings` -> `Other Linker Flags` . Add `-ObjC` complication arguments in debug mode.I just fix this problem.

Hope to solve your problem.